# Django Admin Filter by Related Field Count

Tags: python, django, filter, admin

I am using django 1.27
I have 2 models

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def book_count(self)
        return self.book_set.all().count()

class Book(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

and in the publisther admin i want to be able to filter by book count

```
class PublistherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_filter = ('book_count')
     ....
```

how can i get this to work ?

Comment: [could this help](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/)?

Comment: i have seen that, but it seem that it only valid for a field of the model, you need to add name.alphabetic_filter = True to the model in that example